# Create middle point on the EDGE of Connected Vertices' of an Object in threeJS

Tags: math, 3d, three.js

given Vertices array in Vector3
square vectors3 [{-1,1,0}, {1,1,0}, {-1,-1,0}, {1,-1,0}]
is there any way could be done on Matrix modification and return 4 Verctors?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpTfR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, then:

```
var angle = Math.PI / 4; // rotate 45 deg CCW, negative angle is CW
var m = new THREE.Matrix4();
m.set(
   Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle), 0, 0,
  -Math.sin(angle), Math.cos(angle), 0, 0,
   0              , 0              , 1, 0,
   0              , 0              , 0, Math.sqrt(2) // diagonal length is square root of 2 times of side length
);

var originals = [
  new THREE.Vector3(-1,  1, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3( 1,  1, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3( 1, -1, 0)
];

function applyMatrix(points, matrix4){
  var result = [];
  points.forEach((point)=>{
    result.push(point.clone().applyMatrix4(matrix4));
  })
  return result;
}

var images = applyMatrix(originals, m);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/r1n9wjo1/) example r86

PS The solution is exceptionally for what you gave in the picture.